# To find n-th element in a generator for several times

Tags: python, indexing, generator, subscription

I create a simple generator using

```
x = (i for i in range(100))
```

If I want to find the ***50th*** element I would use `next(itertools.islice(x, 50, None))` to get it, but then I want to find the 25th in [1..100], if I continue to use `next(itertools.islice(x, 25, None))`, I will get ***76*** instead of ***25***.

How can I get different elements by index in a generator?

Comment: Hi sho ryu, have you seen my answer? Did find it helpful? please give some feedbacks. cheers.

Answer (score 0):

There is not such thing as `"getting different elements by Index"` while using a `Generator`.
The results which have been already generated, using `next`, cannot be accessed, again.